# Passing C# variables to Crystal Reports programmatically

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports to create a pretty PDF of a text document with client data in it. What I need to do is pass the job number from the C# code to Crystal Reports so I can put it on top of the PDF document. I have tried a few things that I found on the internet, but to no avail. Anyway to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Why not disclose what you have tried so far and how you have implemented.

If you use crystal report doc object, you can pass on a lot of things, including the conditions. One of the easiest thing is the report parameters. You can capture your inputs using parameter. The other ones include setting report header etc. So once you disclose how you are doing things, I am pretty sure, you shall get the rest of the things very easily.

Comment: Well, actually after posting this, I solved my problem. I was creating a parameter inside of the report and just changing the value inside the code using SetParameterValue(). I discovered that you have to put that after you set the data source, instead of before like I was doing. Thanks for the help though.